# MongoDB installed correctly using Homebrew on Mac but typing "mongo" on the command line gives error: "exception: connect failed"

Tags: mongodb

Mongo wont start on Mac.

1. Typed: "brew tap mongodb/brew"  everything worked fine
2. Typed: "brew install mongodb-community@4.0"  everything worked fine.
3. Typedy: "brew services start mongodb-community@4.0"  everything worked fine.

When i type: "mongo"
I get the following error:
MongoDB shell version v4.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-05-14T17:06:06.551-0400 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed

When I type: "mongodb"  I get the following error at the end of attempting to start:
2019-05-14T17:05:59.227-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-05-14T17:05:59.228-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-05-14T17:05:59.228-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62

Any ideas are appreciated.
Thank you,